# data visualization

Tags: discussion, support

I tried and failed to write my data set in this question. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67090/statistical-significance-of-conditional-probabiltiy it looks ugly. 
how are we supposed to write columns and data?

Comment: What is it you were trying to display? (I can edit it for you, if I can tell what you want.) You can display text in a code block & it will show up as you type it. You can also use mathjax to display information formatted as $\LaTeX$ (see here: [reviewing-questions-and-applying-latex-format](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1604//1605#1605)). Lastly you can use HTML. The editing features CV supports are discussed (briefly) here: [editing-help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: @gung i was trying to show 3 rows and 3 columns of data for 3 different comparisions

Comment: @AndreSilva i found that the tag function could be abused to provide something that looks like a table

Comment: Please do not "abuse" the tag function in this way, @caseyr547. I have tried to edit your question for you. Try to follow my lead & edit it further.

Comment: @gung thanks for the correction i looked on metaoverflow and that seemed to be one of the ways which was suggested.

Comment: That's a poor suggestion. Would you mind posting a link to where it said that? I'd like to address it.

Comment: @gung let me fetch it for you

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables

Comment: Did you see the comments beneath that Meta SO question, casey?  "I'm only serious about the first one."  *The use of tags to present data is an overt joke.* If you were to try this, we would become rather upset at you due to the work required to remove all those tags!

Comment: @whuber i thought it was a kind of invert statmenet when i looked at the code for the first one it was a mess so i thought to myself no way could someone use or suggest all those breaks but as you can tell i was wrong it wont happen again :)

Answer (score 5):

Organization and utility have more value than prettiness.

**Use inline code formatting**, as in

```
Header 1    Header 2     Header 3
123.45      -6.7         abc
8           9.0          xyz
```

This is simple (usually a copy-and-paste operation followed by a click of the `Preformatted text` control) and useful (because readers can copy the data in a format suitable for input with most software).

**$\TeX$ markup is an option** where formatting of the data is essential (which is almost never).  $\TeX$ includes a myriad ways to tabulate things, as in

$$\begin{align}
\text{Header 1}\qquad &\text{Header 2}\qquad &\text{Header 3} \\
123.45\qquad & -6.7\qquad & \text{abc} \\
8\qquad &9.0\qquad &\text{xyz}
\end{align}$$

**Avoid posting data as images** (unless the images, as bitmapped rasters, *are* the data): there is no straightforward way to use such code without manually transcribing it.

[image: Figure]

**Please do not post large amounts (multiple pages) of data**: either strip down the data to a smaller example (which is *much* preferred) or post the full dataset elsewhere and provide a link (which is discouraged because the link may eventually rot).